# Spotify API - Promise stuck on pending

Tags: javascript, html, json, flask, spotify

I'm new to Javascript so please bear with. I'm trying to scrape together a site that I can go to to view my currently playing song on Spotify. It is supposed to make a GET request through the fetch method to the Spotify API every 1000 ms and update the SongNameElement on screen without the user having to refresh.

I used [this code](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/mj9uln/updating_a_variable_on_a_web_page_every_second/gt969m8/#:%7E:text=10%20mo.%20ago-,this,-is%20a%20bare) I found online to get the self-updating div done through a publiclly accessible JSON file.

I also used [this code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#:%7E:text=supplying%20request%20options) to supply the request headers (token etc).

Example JSON Data can be found [here](https://hissmarthome.uk/ExampleData.json). I need the value of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h8Yq.png)

The Spotify API returns a JSON file. I have managed to implement it in Python so far so it's not an issue with authentication to the API. I'm running a flask Python web server that returns JavaScript and HTML (see code below) however whenever it makes a request to the API, the promise is marked as pending however I'm not sure why it is not being completed. Below is my code:

```
import spotipy.util as util
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
    <div id="SongName">Song Name</div>
    <div id="ArtistName">Artist Name</div>
    <script>
      function updateDataOnScreen() {
        const SongNameElement = document.getElementById("SongName")
        FetchResponse = fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing", {
          method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
          mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
          cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer (my token goes here, but has been redacted)'
          },
          redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
          referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => SongNameElement.innerHTML = FetchResponse)
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
        console.log(FetchResponse)
      }
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        setInterval(updateDataOnScreen, 1000) // interval value in milliseconds
      })
    </script>
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Developer Tools shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANQZv.png) constantly.

N.B. I have redacted my token from the headers, so if you run this for yourself, you will need to replace it with your Sptify Token, which you can get [here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track/?market=&additional_types=#:%7E:text=additional_types-,oauth%20token,-Get%20Token).

Comment: You log `FetchResponse` immediately after you create the promise you assign to it (and you create a *new* promise and log it every 1000ms). Why **wouldn't** it always log as pending?

Comment: I suspect your *real* problem (because this stinks of being an XY problem) is that you are assigning `FetchResponse` to `innerHTML` instead of `json`. (Although the resolved value returned by `response.json()` is the JS data structure that was parsed from the JSON and not the JSON itself. So that's going to turn into `[object Object]` when you coerce it to a string)

Comment: So where/what should I change to make the promise finish so I can get to the data?

Comment: Use `then()` to get the data (and deal with the *data* not the promise) instead of logging outside of the promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what I did,  but it works. Cheers Quentin for getting my mind going!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
    <div id="SongName">Song Name</div>
    <script>
      function updateDataOnScreen() {
        const SongNameElement = document.getElementById("SongName")
        FetchResponse = fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing", {
          method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
          mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
          cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer (AUTHKEY)'
          },
          redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
          referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => SongNameElement.innerHTML = (response.item.name))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
      }
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        setInterval(updateDataOnScreen, 1000) // interval value in milliseconds
      })
    </script>
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).